# How to pass ref as a prop in object of component?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I am accessing availableWidgets as a `widget?.component` in GridItem to iterate component but now I want to pass GridItem Ref to widget components.
Give me Suggestion you any.

```
const availableWidgets = [
  {},
  {
    component: <DashboardsGuide />,
    id: "1"
  },

  {
    component: <DashboardsWeather />,
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    component: <DashboardsTraining />,
    id: "3"
  },
];
```

Here, the available widgets content the component and I want to pass parent `ref.current` into this widget but I am not getting idea how to pass ref to its child component while iterating it.

If it is possible then give fruitful suggestion

I had tried `forwardRef` to make it possible but not get succeed.

```
const GridItem = React.forwardRef(function GridItem(
  { className, style, children, item, widget, id, ...rest },
  ref
) {
  return (
    <div
      id={`width-height-${id}`}
      className={`grid-item ${className}`}
      style={style}
      ref={ref}
      {...rest}
    >
      {console.log(ref?.current?.offsetHeight, ref?.current?.offsetWidth)}
      {widget?.component}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});
```

I am using React Grid Layout library.

```
function GridLayout({ layouts, toggle }) {
  return (
    <ResponsiveGridLayout
      // className="layout"
      layouts={layouts}
      rowHeight={20}
      isDraggable={toggle ? true : false}
      isResizable={toggle ? true : false}
      margin={[20, 20]}
      onLayoutChange={(...e) => {
        localStorage.setItem("layouts", JSON.stringify(e[1]));
      }}
      breakpoints={{ lg: 1280, md: 992, sm: 767, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
      cols={{ lg: 24, md: 20, sm: 12, xs: 8, xxs: 4 }}
    >
      {layouts.lg.map((item) => (
        <GridItem id={item.i} key={item.i} widget={availableWidgets[item.i]} />
      ))}
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
  );
}
```

By using

```
{layouts.lg.map((item) => (
    <GridItem id={item.i} key={item.i} widget={availableWidgets[item.i]} />
  ))}
```

I am iterating widgets

Comment: Do you have any control over the `availableWidgets` object shapes? In other words, does `component` need to be JSX? Can it be a reference to the component you want to render?

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: Are you just wanting to pass a React ref through `GridItem` to the `div` element, or the widget component? And where are the refs created/generated?

Comment: I want to pass GridItem ref to widget component.. so i can access GridItem offset property in widget component

Comment: So does `GridItem` need to create the ref to pass to the widget component?

Comment: yes bcz griditem ref generate current offset height and width

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding correctly, `GridItem` needs to create the ref and attach it to the `div`, and pass the ref along to the child widget component to access the current value of (i.e. the offset)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239719/discussion-between-harsh-mendapara-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, `GridItem` needs to create a React ref and attach it to the `div` it's rendering, and pass the ref along to the child widget component to access the current value of (i.e. the offset).

For this I suggest a small change to the `availableWidgets` array so as to allow you to instantiate the components as JSX when rendering and inject any props then.

```
const availableWidgets = [
  {},
  {
    component: DashboardsGuide,
    id: "1"
  },

  {
    component: DashboardsWeather,
    id: "2"
  },
  {
    component: DashboardsTraining,
    id: "3"
  },
];
```

Next have `GridItem` create the React ref, attach it to the `div` and instantiate the widget component to pass the ref in a prop.

```
const GridItem = ({
  className,
  style,
  children,
  item,
  widget = {},
  id,
  ...rest
}) => {
  // (1) Create a React ref
  const gridItemRef = React.useRef();

  // (3) get widget component and rename to valid PascalCase name
  const { component: Widget } = widget;

  // Log the ref values in an intentional side-effect
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const { offsetHeight, offsetWidth } = gridItemRef.current;
    console.log(offsetHeight, offsetWidth);
  });

  return (
    <div
      id={`width-height-${id}`}
      className={`grid-item ${className}`}
      style={style}
      ref={gridItemRef} // (2) attach ref
      {...rest}
    >
      {Widget && <Widget gridItemRef={gridItemRef} />} // (4) render Widget and pass ref prop
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Inside each widget component (`DashboardsGuide`, `DashboardsWeather`, and `DashboardsTraining`) access the passed `GridItem`'s `gridItemRef` via props.

Comment: Some little modification should be there because I want to pass gridItemRef to DashboardsGuide, DashboardsWeather, DashboardsTraining Component which will iterate as per id  in






......

{layouts.lg.map((item) => (
        <GridItem id={item.i} key={item.i} widget={availableWidgets[item.i]} />
      ))}

Comment: @HarshMendapara Can you clarify that comment a bit for me? AFAIK of your ask and the discussed behavior, the `gridItemRef` is passed to those components.

Comment: Sure, As per your solution widget component will receive ref as a prop but i want to pass ref into DashboardsGuide, DashboardsWeather, DashboardsTraining component from GridItem component

Comment: @HarshMendapara Those ***are*** the `DashboardsGuide`, `DashboardsWeather`, `DashboardsTraining` components from `availableWidgets`, now computed at runtime. 

Comment: @HarshMendapara Hopefully [Choosing the type as runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) illustrates what is happening here. With `widget={availableWidgets[item.i]}` `availableWidgets[item.i]` is *possibly* one of those dashboard components, passed on a `widget` prop. In `GridItem` `const { component: Widget } = widget;` is accessing the `component` property to have a reference to the dashboard component and rename it to `Widget` so it's a valid React component name, and then render it as JSX and pass the extraneous props to it.